# How to start application from a different location in ubuntu

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, gaming

ok, so I have multiple versions of a game running(minecraft). I use one version of minecraft for my younger brother, and one for myself. In windows, there's my minecraft.bat file:

```
set APPDATA=E:\backup\Minecraft\minecraft folders\1.8 MC\data
bin\minecraft.exe
```

this is for me, and starts minecraft from mu hard drive, instead of Appdata. now I completely removed windows, and use an ubuntu-only computer. is there any way to do this?

Comment: is there any way to do this in ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, (I only have a basic working know how of how to run minecraft server) you would want something like this.

Install screen if you dont already have it

```
sudo apt-get install screen

screen -S "Minecraft server Me"

cd /location/of/minecraft/config/
```

Fire up the minecraft server once you have located the config like this

`java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar minecraft_server.jar nogu`

For your brother

```
screen -S "Minecraft server Brother"

cd /location/of/minecraft/configforbrother/
```

Start up his instance

```
java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar minecraft_serverbrother.jar nogui
```

This however will only allow you to run one minecraft server at a time. You can however change the port the the minecraft server binds to when it starts and run multiple minecraft servers at the same time.

Have a look [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-minecraft-server-on-linux) for more indepth explantions on how to run minecraft on linux

Comment: what? it didn't work

Comment: You need to change this - cd /location/of/minecraft/config/ to the actual directory. Did you follow the guide I posted at the bottom?

Comment: but this is for a server. it doesn't work for me.

Comment: by config do you mean the ".minecraft" folder?

Comment: this is the title of the guide "How To Set Up a Minecraft Server on Linux".

Comment: ya, but i'm asking how to start minecraft from a different location, not home/.minecraft

Comment: copy the contents of the folder to a different location and when starting the minecraft server start it from within your alternative location

Comment: but i'm not starting a server. i'm just starting the client in a different location.